# My Button Links Are Concatenating with my site url

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I was building my web site with Elementor and out of nowhere my buttons stopped working. Now when I click on them the link goes to site `url+link`. For example, the button should link to `google.com`. Now it links to `www.sitename/postname/google.com`

I've built a [test page](https://juvenalvalentim.com.br/teste/) with a button that should lead to google.com.

Answer (score 0):

I whasn't using "https://" on my links...